# How to get an array of .png files in a folder using Bash

Tags: linux, bash

Hi I am a newbe to bash programming and need some help. I am building a pipeline for image processing. I would like to be able to take the png images in a folder and pass them to clusterImage.pl once that is done I would like to then pass the outputted file to seperateObjects.pl the outputted file is of the same name but has kmeansOutput.all.matrix attached to the end. Below is what I have so far, but it is not working. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
#!/bin/bash
#This script will take in an image and a matrix file.
#The output will be an image and a matrix file.

list=`ls *.png`
for i in $list
do
$file="./$list"
$image_array = $list
echo $file
#Cheching to see if the file exists.
for((j=0;j<=i;j++))
do
if [ -e image_array[j] ]; then
echo $file
echo "Begining processing"
#Take in an image and create a matrix from it.
perl clusterImage.pl SampleImage.png
#Take in a matrix and draw a picture showing the centers of all
#of the colonies.
perl seperateObjects.pl SampleImage.png.kmeansOutput.all.matrix
echo "Ending processing"
else
echo "There is an issue"
fi
done
done
```

Comment: Try using the `-x` option to [debug your bash script](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html).

Comment: "not working" doesn't provide any information. Please post error messages or specific deviations from expected behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a few problems (or potential improvements) with your code:

1. You don't need the loop `for i in $list` because you never use `$i` in the script - that results in just doing the same thing over and over again (the same number of times as the number of `.png` files in the directory)
2. You don't need to use a Bash array, since Bash can iterate over the different filenames in a list like `*.png`.
3. I suspect you mean to run `perl clusterImage.pl` on each `.png` file in the directory... or did you? It's kind of hard to tell. Edit your question to explain more clearly what you mean to do, and I can edit my answer accordingly.
4. You can use short-circuiting, as they call it, instead of an `if` statement: `[ -f file.png ] && echo "file exists"` is shorter than

   ```
   if [ -f file.png ]; then
       echo "file exists"
   fi
   ```

If I understand what you're trying to do (and I'm not sure I do), I think this might work for you. For each image in the directory, this will run `perl clusterImage.pl <name_of_image.png>` and `perl separateObjects.pl <name_of_image.png>.kmeansOutput.all.matrix`.

```
for image in *.png
do
  [[ -f $image ]] && perl clusterImage.pl $image && perl separateObjects.pl $image.kmeansOutput.all.matrix
done
```

Answer (score 8):

this should work:

```
for file in *.png; do
    # do stuff with your file:
    perl clusterImage.pl "$file";
    # …
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to have an array, it is possible: [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: Arrays](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html)

But perhaps it would be better (or at least simpler) to either modify your Perl script to handle a list of files, or handle each image separately.

Answer (score 1):

You don't normally want to have dollar signs on variable names on the left hand side of an assignment.

You *could* make an array like this: `image_array=($(ls *.png))` but that fails if filenames have spaces in them.

[Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), though, for that reason at least.

[Don't use backticks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082), use `$()` instead.

You have nested for loops that seem to be in conflict with each other. The structure in [**knittl's** answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095756/how-to-get-an-array-of-png-files-in-a-folder-using-bash/3095800#3095800) is the one you should use.